# Find Distance Between Two Points

Tags: analytic-geometry

If we are to find the distance between the points $P(0,0)$ and $Q(-2,-3)$, then we can use the Theorem of Pythagoras for this purpose.

> $distance (P,Q) = \sqrt{(x_2 -x_1)^2 + (y_2 -y_1)^2}$

therefore, $\text{distance} (P,Q) = \sqrt{-5}$ But the answer is undefined. Is this answer and the reason correct?

Answer (score 4):

You are calculating wrong:

$distance(P,Q) = \sqrt{(x_2 -x_1)^2 + (y_2 -y_1)^2}=\sqrt{((-2)^2+(-3)^2)}=\sqrt{(13)}$.

Comment: oh yes! Sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to square.
$d(P,Q) = \sqrt{(-2)^2+(-3)^2} = \sqrt{4+9} = \sqrt{13}$.